# Flutter: How do I pass a parameter from one screen to another without changing the screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have started using flutter recently and currently am on the navigation. What I want is to know if there is a way to pass a parameter from one widget to another (or one screen to another) without having to call the builder function and changing the screen? I have looked at onGenerateRoute and navigators but they all cause a change in screen. Is there a way to block this change during navigator.push()?

What I actually want is very simple. I want a toggle button to pass a boolean value to a widget that reads it and applies it into a conditional statement.

Comment: Why do you need a new Widget/Screen for that? If the only thing you want is your toggle to have an affect on the UI you should use a `StatefulWidget` and the `setState` method.

Comment: If you want to pass only a boolean value to somewhere, you can use sharedpreferences to keep it's value, or need to a apply something you can use function but how will work that widget or page without building? If you give more information what's your main goal then maybe we can suggest something else.

Comment: @puelo is it possible to setState of the sibling (or parent widget) through an on pressed event of the widget in question? Lets say I have a a toggle button that gives a boolean value of true but how can I send that to a sibling or parent widget. Or even a child widget without Navigating to it?

Comment: @erbazkamran If the parent rebuilds because of setState all children will also be rebuild. You can just pass the boolean into the constructor of the child widget and it should get rebuild then aswell.

Comment: @puelo then is there a way to send over data from the child to the parent? I have read about VoidCallback and will look into it as a solution for my problem. Do you think that is a correct method or should I use maybe a State Management system like BLoC? Thanks for the responses.

Comment: If it will become a bigger app than i suggest you use some kind of State Management, yes. Flutter has build-in state management i believe, but you have to choose what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:

```dart
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage(
                      value: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),



class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool value;

  const SecondPage({Key key, @required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't this change screens as well? How can I have the same effect but without having that change?

Comment: @erbaz kamran I have same problem, did you get a solution?